# How to add page-breaks to generated multiple page pdf

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, pdf

I've created a project where I need to generate multiple `5.5in W x 8.5in H` Cards for print. I place each card on a landscape page of `11in W x 8.5in H`. So 2 cards on 1 page.
My current PDF has 77 half page cards and should result in a 38.5 page PDF.

The problem I'm running into is with the css properties for page-break:

```
page-break-after: auto | always | avoid | left | right
page-break-before: auto | always | avoid | left | right
page-break-inside: auto | avoid

Detailed descriptions of each css page break possible value:

auto: Initial value. Automatic page breaks.
always: Always force page breaks before/after the element.
avoid: Avoid page breaks before/after/inside the element.
left: Force page breaks before/after the element so that the next page is formatted as a left page.
right: Force page breaks before/after the element so that the next page is formatted as a right page.
```

**Problem**

All 77 cards are being laid on top of each other in a 1 page PDF. (*There are 77 card on top of each other in this image*)
[image]

I need them to break after 2 cards have been placed to make up the 38.5 pages.

**Here is what I'm doing:** I'm looping through the database to generate the cards needed and applying a class of `card_one_bg` and `card_two_bg` to place the cards on the left side and right side of the page. I do this by checking the card count for Odd and Even. Odd = Left side & Even = Right side.

```
    @php
    $rows = 0;
    @endphp
    @foreach($haitiKids as $index =>$hk)
    @php
    $nummReceived = $hk->sponsors_received;
    $nummNeeded = $hk->sponsors_needed - $nummReceived;
    @endphp
    @for($i = 0; $i < $hk->sponsors_needed; $i++ )
        @if($nummReceived-- <= 0) @php $rows++;
    @endphp
    <div class="cutline"></div>
    <!-- Class "page" = the 11in W x 8.5in H page -->
            <div class="page">
                    <!-- CARD START: Class "card_one_bg" = left side of page | Class "card_two_bg" = right side of page -->
                    <div class="{{ ($rows % 2 === 0) ? 'card_one_bg' : 'card_two_bg'}}">
                       ...ALL CARD CONTENT
                    <!-- CARD END -->
                    @endif
                    @endfor
                </div>
            @endforeach
```

**Here is the relevant Css:**

```
    .page {
        position: absolute;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 11in;
        height: 8.5in;
        font-family: "Muli", sans-serif;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }

    .break-left {
        page-break-after: left;
    }

    .break-right {
        page-break-after: always;
    }

    .no-break {
        page-break-inside: always;
    }
```

I was messing around with some helper classes listed above: `.break-left`, `.break-right`, `.no-break` .. no luck

I'm been at this for days doing a bunch of trial and error, but if I do get the pages to break, the left side is blank on one page and the right side is blank on the next page and so-on. Like this:
[image]

I'd be happy to provide more info if need. Any help would be appreciated.

PS: Using the laravel/dompdf package to generate the pdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following snippet.

```css
.page-break {
    page-break-after: always;
}
```

```html
<!-- Class "page" = the 11in W x 8.5in H page -->
<div class="page">
    @php
      $rows = 0;
    @endphp
    @foreach($haitiKids as $index =>$hk)
     @php
      $nummReceived = $hk->sponsors_received;
      $nummNeeded = $hk->sponsors_needed - $nummReceived;
     @endphp
     @for($i = 0; $i < $hk->sponsors_needed; $i++ )
      @if($nummReceived-- <= 0) 
       @php $rows++; @endphp
                    <!-- CARD START: Class "card_one_bg" = left side of page | Class "card_two_bg" = right side of page --> <!-- you may not need these clases for left and right because page break will be inserted as a div between pages -->
                    
                    @php if($rows % 2 ===0) { 
                      echo '</div><!-- end .page-->';
                      echo '
                        <div class="cutline"></div><!-- cut line if you need this - maybe make the save div add cut line and page break-->';
                      echo '<div class="page-break"></div><!-- end .page-->';
                      echo '<div class="page"><!-- new .page-->';
                      }
                    @endphp
                    <div class="{{ ($rows % 2 === 0) ? 'card_one_bg' : 'card_two_bg'}}">
                       ...ALL CARD CONTENT
                    <!-- CARD END -->
                    @endif
                    @endfor
            @endforeach
                </div>
```